# Differences between class_weight and scale_pos weight in LightGBM

Tags: classification, class-imbalance, lightgbm

I have a very imbalanced dataset with the ratio of the positive samples to the negative samples being 1:496. The scoring metric is the f1 score and my desired model is LightGBM. I am using the sklearn implementation of LightGBM.

I have read the docs on the `class_weight` parameter in LightGBM:

> class_weight : dict, 'balanced' or None, optional (default=None) Weights associated with classes in the form {class_label: weight}. Use this parameter only for multi-class classification task; for binary classification task you may use is_unbalance or scale_pos_weight parameters. The 'balanced' mode uses the values of y to automatically adjust weights inversely proportional to class frequencies in the input data as n_samples / (n_classes * np.bincount(y)). If None, all classes are supposed to have weight one. Note that these weights will be multiplied with sample_weight (passed through the fit method) if sample_weight is specified.

On using the `class_weight` parameter on my dataset, which is a binary classification problem, I got a much better score (0.7899) than when I used the recommended `scale_pos_weight` parameter (0.2388). Should I use the `class_weight` parameter or the `scale_pos_weight` parameter to balance the classes?

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but the docs say to use 'is_unbalance', which I presume is the "class_weight" equivalent. Note that your probabilities will be haywire after this, and you will want to calibrate if you intend to use the probabilities.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/413596/232706

Answer (score 13):

You can achieve the same results by using either `class_weight`, `scale_pos_weight` and `is_unbalanced` for binary classification on unbalanced dataset.

Setting

```
class_weight = {0: (number of negative samples / number of positive samples), 
                1: (number of positive samples / number of negative samples)}
```

is the same as setting `is_unbalance = True` or `scale_pos_weight = (no. of negative samples / number of positive samples)`.

Comment: The argument is `scale_pos_weight` not `scale_pos_weights`.